# how change type of column in radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I mean - I write data to database using RadMaskedEditBox. But I load data from database using generated from `Add new data source` table adapter. So the data from maskededitbox is in the 5th column(I've got 7 columns). I need a GridViewMaskBoxColumn. But new column can be added only as the last column. So I delete column which(contains data from radmaskededitbox) from datagrid, copy its data to gridviewmaskboxcolumn and the add it to datagrid. But when I call update method - all the data from new column dissapears.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the auto generated column, and add a new GridViewMaskBoxColumn to the desired position. You can use the Insert method of the Columns collection to insert the column at the desired position.

In order to show the data from the database, please make sure that you specify the correct FieldName of the GridViewMaskBoxColumn, pointing to the field in your data table.

Here is a sample:

```
radGridView1.Columns.Remove(radGridView1.Columns["theDefaultColumnName"]);
GridViewMaskBoxColumn maskCol = new GridViewMaskBoxColumn();
maskCol.FieldName = "dataTableFieldName";
radGridView1.Columns.Insert(4, maskCol);
```